# Maximize throughput with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

In our project, we want to use the RabbitMQ in "Task Queues" pattern to pass data.

On the producer side, we build a few TCP server(in node.js) to recv
high concurrent data and send it to MQ without doing anything.

On the consumer side, we use JAVA client to get the task data from
MQ, handle it and then ack.

So the question is:
To get the maximum message passing throughput/performance( For example, 400,000 msg/second) , How many queues is best?  Does that more queue means better throughput/performance? And is there anything else should I notice?
Any known best practices guide for using RabbitMQ in such scenario?

Any comments are highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For best performance in RabbitMQ, follow the advice of its creators. From the [RabbitMQ blog](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/24/sizing-your-rabbits/):

> **RabbitMQ's queues are fastest when they're empty**. When a queue is
>   empty, and it has consumers ready to receive messages, then as soon as
>   a message is received by the queue, it goes straight out to the
>   consumer. In the case of a persistent message in a durable queue, yes,
>   it will also go to disk, but that's done in an asynchronous manner and
>   is buffered heavily. The main point is that very little book-keeping
>   needs to be done, very few data structures are modified, and very
>   little additional memory needs allocating.

If you really want to dig deep into the performance of RabbitMQ queues, this [other blog entry](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/10/27/performance-of-queues-when-less-is-more/) of theirs goes into the data much further.

Comment: That's stream processing, not queue-ing. They should rename it "RabbitMS" (Rabbit Message Stream).

Answer (score 37):

According to a response I once got from the rabbitmq-discuss mailing group there are other things that you can try to increase throughput and reduce latency:

> - Use a larger prefetch count. Small values hurt performance.
> - A topic exchange is slower than a direct or a fanout exchange.
> - Make sure queues stay short. Longer queues impose more processing
>     overhead.
> - If you care about latency and message rates then use smaller messages.
>     Use an efficient format (e.g. avoid XML) or compress the payload.
> - Experiment with HiPE, which helps performance.
> - Avoid transactions and persistence. Also avoid publishing in immediate
>     or mandatory mode. Avoid HA. Clustering can also impact performance.
> - You will achieve better throughput on a multi-core system if you have
>     multiple queues and consumers.
> - Use at least v2.8.1, which introduces flow control. Make sure the
>     memory and disk space alarms never trigger.
> - Virtualisation can impose a small performance penalty.
> - Tune your OS and network stack. Make sure you provide more than enough
>     RAM. Provide fast cores and RAM.

Comment: Is a topic exchange slower because it takes the exchange longer time to compute to which queue it needs to send a message?

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of generalized noise and low-impact to irrelevant advice. I'm surprised they didn't list "just send fewer messages" as a performance tip.   You cannot use direct if you need topic queues.  Increasing your prefetch can dramatically INCREASE latency, too. You have to follow the docs and guidance for setting the correct value for your situation.  Multicore systems are faster? Yeah, water is wet. Keep queues short? Um, just throw away extra messages? Some of this is just plain silly.  HiPE is going to buy you practically ZERO benefit in most applications.

Answer (score 2):

You will increase the throughput with a larger prefetch count AND at the same time ACK multiple messages (instead of sending ACK for each message) from your consumer.

But, of course, ACK with multiple flag on (http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.ack) requires extra logic on your consumer application (http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-August/029600.html). You will have to keep a list of delivery-tags of the messages delivered from the broker, their status (whether your application has handled them or not) and ACK every N-th delivery-tag (NDTAG) when all of the messages with delivery-tag less than or equal to NDTAG have been handled.

Comment: Sorry, just patently false: "you will increase the throughput with a larger prefetch count".  Prefetch requires tuning and it's not a constant even then.  The documentation details this.

Comment: @RickO'Shea Please read carefully both the question and the answer, and then add a comment.